# Perl Replace 26 characters with numeric

Tags: regex, perl, tr

I would like to replace a string with the numerical correspondent.

For example (one-liner on Windows):

```
perl -e "$_ = \"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\"; tr\a-z\1-9\;"
```

The result is:

```
12345678999999999999999999
```

This works until 9 but how I can assign the numeric correspondent after character i?
I would like to know how I can assign 2 sign to one 1 sign,

for example,

```
12 -> j, 13 -> k, etc.
```

To identify the numerical value it would makes sense to assign

```
"1-", "2-", ... "25-", "26".
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -E"$_ = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; s/([a-z])/ord($1)-96/ge; say;"
```

or if you have 5.14+

```
perl -E"say 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' =~ s/([a-z])/ord($1)-96/ger;"
```

You can substitute any rule instead of `ord($1) - 96`.

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot. I didn't know ord(). Is it possible to at a hyphon to get 1-2-3-4 .....-26-?

Comment: @giordano The second part of `s///` is just Perl code. So `(ord($1) - 96) . '-'`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that it is possible to use brackets in that way. Now I understand what you mean with "just Perl": It is not regex-syntax. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe `tr///` can do that unfortunately - it's a one-to-one character substitution. So you're going to have to go the long way round:

```
my %indicies = map { $_ => (ord($_) - ord('a')) + 1 } ('a' .. 'z');
my $result = join '', map { $indicies{$_} } split(//, $string);
```

Unfortunately that's not a one-liner.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the code. It is helpfull for similar issues.